# Disable Cookies from cdnjs.cloudflare.com?

Tags: html, cookies, cloudflare

So I programmed a website and was just looking at it online. But then I noticed that one tracker is blocked. I looked and it seems to be a tracker called cdnjs.cloudflare.com. Sure, I use cloudflare's tags, but how can I prevent a tracker from showing up there? Or can I prevent that from happening at all?

Here are the tags (maybe there is something wrong?):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.js" integrity="sha512-ZKNVEa7gi0Dz4Rq9jXcySgcPiK+5f01CqW+ZoKLLKr9VMXuCsw3RjWiv8ZpIOa0hxO79np7Ec8DDWALM0bDOaQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Here is a screenshot of the tracker [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIAYh.png).

I did not find anything online so I asked here. I'm open to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `jquery.waypoints.js` and `font-awesome 6.2.1 css` by using `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` as a cdn to deliver your libraries to your website.

If you don't want to show up `cdnjs.cloudflare.com`, you can download the library and upload it into your website and link it like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-6.2.1.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" />`

More info: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/